# why does bootstrap carousel take margin on its left and right side automatically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a carousel with full screen. That means I need my carousel 100% wide literally. But it is leaving some place on its left and right side. Other elements are working fine. Here is the image:

[image]

My Code is:

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="images/slide-1.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/slide-2.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="images/slide-3.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 300px; background: #990000;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

How to remove these unwanted margins?

Comment: can you post the link of your site here? it's easy to debug there..

Comment: Do you use vanilla bootstrap? Check your body margins and padding. You can use Inspect Element feature (click on these empty gaps with right click and select "Inspect element") and it will highlight CSS that causes these margins.

Comment: It is running on localhost of my computer @Sam Teng Wong

Comment: you can do inspect element on your browser and debug your css there....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is because .container already have padding-right: 15px; padding-left: 15px; so you need to create a new class to overwrite  by making padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;

```
<div class="container-fluid header">
...
</div>
```

`.header {padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0;}`

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
 <style>
      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {

          margin: 0 auto;
      }
      </style>
```

else try this

```
.carousel .item {
    width: 100%; /*slider width*/
    max-height: 400px; /*slider height*/
}
.carousel .item img {
    width: 100%; /*img width*/
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .block {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
}
```